# Reusable ClojureScript Libraries

Tags: clojure, package, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript

So, I took my large Clojure project and split it into two.

I compiled the core part and made an Uberjar.

Then typed :

```
lein deploy clojars
```

to make that jar public, and then added it as a dependency in the project.clj file for my application.

This code is written in cljx so it can compile to javascript.

What are the equivalent steps I need to make my two cljx codebases into two separate javascript libraries, without having the whole ClojureScript virtual machine repeated twice?

Update : Just to clarify a couple of things.

1) I know I can move to .cljc rather than .cljx. My only concern is that this seems pretty new and I don't know if existing users of my code are likely to have it. But I probably will make this move shortly. Answers in terms of cljc are also welcome.

2) I am already successfully compiling my code to a single monolithic main.js file. What I'm looking for is how to compile separate libraries of cljs that can be included in other cljs projects. As every time I currently compile something in cljs I get a main.js file with the entire clojurescript VM.

3) One of my motivations for coming back to this question is that I want to start using Figwheel. So I want to be able to make libraries in clojurescript that I can drop into a new clojurescript project I'm developing through Figwheel. So I imagine I'd be referencing them in this new project's project.clj file, and including them within the web-page as already compiled .js files. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Would be great if you can share the `project.clj` from both projects. There are multiple things that can go wrong in a .cljx configuration: `:output-path`, `:source-path`, `:resource-path`, also how you declare the dependency (using `:aot` could be a problem), if you are calling `cljx once` before `deploy clojars` or not...

Comment: thanks @nberger. I can, but what I'm really looking for is an overview / tutorial (or pointer to one) on how this works. So I can understand it. I'm not trying to debug my current setup. Just a basic explanation would be great.

Comment: I added an answer that I think pinpoints the most important parts you should take into account, and also includes some links if you want  to dig deeper.

Comment: Looking to your updated question, I would say: yes, you are wrong, you don't want to include them as compiled .is files. You want the library to provide the clojurescript code as if they were resources in the class path, so they are going to be available in the cljsbuils environment of the project using the library.

Comment: AFAIK you would only consume your library as .js coffee if you are going to do it from .js ( not cljs) code. In that case you would have to :export the "public" symbols so their names do not get munged among other things

Comment: So ... are you saying that you never distribute clojurescript libraries to other projects in compiled form? Always as raw source? And that the consuming project always recompiles everything into a single large js file? What about, say, when I'm working with Figwheel, which as far as I can see doesn't seem to include the clojurescript VM at all in the browser?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. See the prismatic/schema jar as an example: `curl -O https://clojars.org/repo/prismatic/schema/0.4.0/schema-0.4.0.jar && unzip schema-0.4.0.jar`. You won't find any `.js` file there, only `.cljs` and `.clj` files. And it is certainly used as a library, from clj and cljs projects, using figwheel or not. By the way, when you work with figwheel, you will get the "clojurescript VM" (you mean the `cljs.core` and related namespaces) into the browser.

Comment: See https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Dependencies for more info on how dependencies are packaged and loaded.

Comment: Thanks @nberger That feels like it's the beginning of the answer I was looking for (ie. that ClojureScript expects to include libs in source form rather than compiled, and that you still compile your application monolithically). Does that mean it's not expected to use ClojureScript to make components for ordinary web-developers? Only ones who have the ClojureScript compiler?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. It's just that you need to :export what you want to expose, like I briefly explained above. For more details about that, consider asking a new question specific to that topic.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Leiningen's checkout dependencies feature?

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say what's wrong or missing from your configuration without having more details about your `project.clj`, but I'll try to cover the most important parts where you should take a look at.

### Do not use cljx. Use Reader Conditionals!

Nowadays, **[cljx is deprecated](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx#this-plugin-is-deprecated) in favor of Reader Conditionals (cljc)**. If you have the chance to upgrade to clojure 1.7.0 then my suggestion is to do that and **leave cljx behind**: You'll avoid much of the issues from cljx because instead of using a build tool (that needs to be in sync with the rest of the build pipeline) cljc is something that the clojure compiler is aware of.

### If you are still going to use cljx...

I won't repeat all the stuff covered in the excellent [README from cljx](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx#usage) but just pinpoint some relevant parts:

1. You have to be sure `cljx once` is called before other tasks down in the pipeline (`javac`, `compile`, `uberjar` and even `test` or `cljsbuild test`). So you might want to create `aliases` or modify the default `:prep-tasks` in your `project.clj`. More info: see [the Installation section](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx#installation)
2. Your cljx `:output-path` should be added to your cljsbuild `:source-paths`. See [the Usage section](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx#usage)

Last but not least:

3. Do not declare your dependency as `:classifier "aot"` in your dependencies vector when using cljsbuild. Use it only if you know what you are doing. Remove it during development if you have dependency issues. This applies whether you are using cljx, cljc or just plain cljs.
4. Take a look to other projects cljx configurations. For example: [Prismatic/schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema/blob/a26b039f887e54b9989648510e7c17ec41402a85/project.clj) and the ["Switch to reader conditionals" commit in Sablono](https://github.com/r0man/sablono/commit/61ac85798167070aa9ad0d597163663c49cfecd2#diff-0fff143854a4f5c0469a3819b978a483)

Comment: nberger. Is this an answer to my question?

I am already successfully compiling cljx to cljs. The problem is, I'm only getting a single monolithic main.js. What I want to know is how to break my monolithic cljs up into separate projects that give me separate js files that can be installed / included  within other projects.

Comment: @interstar well yes, it was intended as an answer to your question, it's just that maybe I didn't understand your exact issue. I think I now got it: you don't have to worry about how the compiled js output is included in your uberjar but how your cljs files are included in the uberjar so they are available as clojurescript code. The most common way to do that is to have an output-path that is then added as resource-paths, you can see that in the prismatic schema project.clj linked from my answer. Another option is the sablono's way: output to target/classes